# Why is Thread.CurrentPrincipal not persisting after async await call

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, .net-4.7.2, synchronizationcontext

I have the following code:

```
public async Task Get()
{
    // With .ConfigureAwait(false): "AspNetSynchronizationContext"
    // Without .ConfigureAwait(false): "AspNetSynchronizationContext"
    var synchContext = SynchronizationContext.Current.GetType().Name;

    // With .ConfigureAwait(false): "david.klempfner@email.com"
    // Without .ConfigureAwait(false): "david.klempfner@email.com"
    var originalName = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new CustomPrincipal("A");

    // With .ConfigureAwait(false): "A"
    // Without .ConfigureAwait(false): "A"
    var name = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;

    await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
    //await Task.Delay(1000);

    // With .ConfigureAwait(false): null
    // Without .ConfigureAwait(false): "AspNetSynchronizationContext"
    var newSynchContext = SynchronizationContext.Current?.GetType().Name;

    // With .ConfigureAwait(false): "A"
    // Without .ConfigureAwait(false): "david.klempfner@email.com"
    var newName = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
}
```

I set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` to `new CustomPrincipal("A")`, then if I call `await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false)`, the value is persisted afterwards.

However, if I call `Task.Delay(1000)`, the value is not persisted, and `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` still contains its original value.

This seems like the opposite of what should happen based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31347443/2063755):

> ASP.NET uses its SynchronizationContext to set
> Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

I thought if you use `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, the original context is not put back, which I thought would have contained the original `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`.

Is `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` linked to the synchronization context? If so, why is the value that I set for it not persisted when I return to the original context?

**Update:**

I have `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="4.5" enableVersionHeader="false" />`, and `<compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" debug="true">` set in web.config.

However, `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>` is set in .csproj.

Comment: I think you have all the answers in the "answer" link you provided. Read all the answers from there. I think the most relevant explanation about "SynchronizationContext" is that   "The execution context is returned to its previous state when the method completes."

Comment: What's your `httpRuntime.targetFramework` set to?

Comment: @StephenCleary 4.5. Which I find strange because it has `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>` in my .csproj file.